# Clojure "already refers to" exception for Hiccup's with-base-url

Tags: clojure, leiningen, apache-storm, hiccup

I am going through Liberator's Getting Started guide. At the very beginning, when trying to evaluate the above namespace declaration

```
(ns restserver.core
  (:require [liberator.core :refer [resource defresource]]
            [ring.middleware.params :refer [wrap-params]]
            [compojure.core :refer [defroutes ANY]]))
```

i get

```
;!!CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: with-base-url already refers to: #'hiccup.core/with-base-url in namespace: hiccup.page, compiling:(hiccup/page.clj:1:1)
```

List of declared dependencies in `project.clj` looks like this:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [liberator "0.13"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.apache.storm/storm-core "0.9.5"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]]
```

It seems that `storm-core` dependency is causing this issue, as when i remove it, the problem is gone. How can i fix this problem? (apart from moving Storm-related code to a separate library)?

**UPDATE:** there is [an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-169) on Storm project JIRA posted for exactly this problem.

Comment: I am not an expert in Clojure.... However, it seems that the dependency is kind of a duplicate. Does storm-core somehow includes the same dependency resulting in a conflict? Is it possible to "remove" transitive dependencies?

Comment: I don't have the time to write a full answer right now, but this is fixed with the `:provided` key which describes deps that will be provided by the host at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding `hiccup` from the `storm-core` by providing exclusions on `project.clj`:

`:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [liberator "0.13"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.apache.storm/storm-core "0.9.5" :exclusions [hiccup]]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]]`

Comment: Tried adding the line, but it didn't help.